# DP5 errors in IOHIDEventQueue.c

Tags: ios, xcode5

I was working on XCode5-DP4 and I switched to DP5.

Now I have this nasty errors on my logs:

```
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
```

Any ideas? I don't even know where to start searching.

Comment: DPs are under NDA, you shouldn't discuss them outside of Apple's developer forums.

Comment: Seeing this as well. File a radar.

Comment: Since developer previews are under NDA, I can’t post an answer on Stack Overflow. However, I can point you to a [workaround](https://devforums.apple.com/message/861956#861956) on Apple’s Developer Forums (iOS developer program required).

Comment: This should be on apple forum because under NDA

Comment: The workaround on Apple's developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/861956#861956

Comment: Same for me ): on DP4

Comment: Same for me, but the Apple Developer forums gives me this 5th Aug Apple Developer Update. Can anyone post the workaround? oh Apple, see what's happening when you post a new beta after just a week..?

Comment: I have also seen this recently in Xcode 4.6. Re-open.

Comment: This is specific to iOS 7 Beta 5 and therefore all versions of Xcode will experience the log flood.

Comment: @0xced thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks * (unsigned int)-1! :)

Comment: wait for stable xcode version or ignore it.

Comment: I have created a radar for this: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5252212427063296

Answer (score 17, accepted):

change your main.m file with this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "QDAppDelegate.h"

typedef int (*PYStdWriter)(void *, const char *, int);
static PYStdWriter _oldStdWrite;

int __pyStderrWrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size)
{
    if ( strncmp(buffer, "AssertMacros:", 13) == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
return _oldStdWrite(inFD, buffer, size);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    _oldStdWrite = stderr->_write;
    stderr->_write = __pyStderrWrite;
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([QDAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a bug in Xcode 5 DP5. Just ignore it, it will go away <del>in the next BETA build</del> eventually.

Comment: its still there in DP6 so your prediction dissapointingly was wrong sir

Comment: Yep, it's still there, and I'm pretty sure that it's the source of the crash problem when launching my app :/